# Bounce out clickable graphics with Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to create a circle that when you hover over it smaller circles will come into view and be clickable. Example found [here](http://liftinteractive.com/expertise/) - hover over the brain, heart or hand.

I've tried two different ways to recreate this animation and both don't quite work:

Hover function on the main circle [codepen](http://codepen.io/linddss/full/bagjq/)

```
paper.circle(300,200,50)
.attr ({
fill : "orange",
stroke: "none"
}).hover (function() {
c1.animate({cx: 450}, 1000, "bounce");
c2.animate({cx: 150}, 1000, "bounce");
c3.animate({cy: 50}, 1000, "bounce");
c4.animate({cy: 350}, 1000, "bounce");
}, function () {
c1.animate({cx: 300}, 500);
c2.animate({cx: 300}, 500);
c3.animate({cy: 200}, 500);
c4.animate({cy: 200}, 500);
});
```

This means the smaller circles disappear when you move your mouse off of the main circle, which means that I'm not able to make the smaller circle a clickable event since you can't move your mouse to them without them disappearing.

I next tried making the hover over a rect that surrounds the area but I am getting really weird results and the hover functions aren't working at all. See [codepen](http://codepen.io/linddss/full/oFAhu/).

```
paper.rect(0,0,600,400).hover (function() {
c1.animate({cx: 450}, 1000, "bounce");
c2.animate({cx: 150}, 1000, "bounce");
c3.animate({cy: 50}, 1000, "bounce");
c4.animate({cy: 350}, 1000, "bounce");
}, function () {
c1.animate({cx: 300}, 500);
c2.animate({cx: 300}, 500);
c3.animate({cy: 200}, 500);
c4.animate({cy: 200}, 500);
});
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Taking the first example, the circles disappear when you hover out. Do you mean you don't want them to disappear when you hover out (just remove the hoverout stuff then)? When do you want them to disappear ?

Comment: In my example they hover out as soon as you leave the circle meaning that you cannot click on the smaller circles. The example I'm showing from liftinteractive the little objects stay until you've hovered out of the area instead of just the centre image which means you can click on them since they don't immediately disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close. In the original example, the hover works over an area rather than the circle, so this would logically be the better option. There would probably be 2 issues though.

1. When you hover over the rect, if you then hover over a circle, it would steal the event, causing it to back out.
   This can be got around with a style on the circles of

`circle { pointer-events: none }`

2. The rect would need a fill, so you would just need to add..

`rect.attr({ fill: 'white' })`

[jsbin](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xheag)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! Works great, I was wondering if there is a way to do this with a transparent background.If you look [here](http://codepen.io/linddss/full/JBlmD/) you can see the eventual use for the code is to hove over the symbols and have smaller symbols pop out. Thanks again for the response!

Comment: I'm not quite sure without seeing an attempt in action. I'm not quite sure if it needs to be transparent (you may get away with opacity 0.001, it won't work with totally transparent or invisible), or just underneath (ie added before in the dom), so the other stuff appears on top. Then have pointer-events: none on anything that you don't want to have interfere maybe ? You may have to think about what happens if any areas overlap you want to hover over.